# How to detect phone handset brand and model info on Brew?

Tags: c, version, brew-framework, brewmp

How do I runtime detect which make and model a phone is, which is running Brew or Brew MP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you have USB logging enabled

```
printdevinfo(s, AEE_DEVICEITEM_MODEL_NAME); 
printdevinfo(s, AEE_DEVICEITEM_MANUFACTURER_NAME); 
printdevinfo(s, AEE_DEVICEITEM_FRIENDLY_NAME);
```

and if printdevinfo is defined like this:

```
static void printdevinfo(IShell* s, int id) 
{ 
    AECHAR* pItemBuff;
    int nItemLen = 0; 

    ISHELL_GetDeviceInfoEx(s, AEE_DEVICEITEM_MANUFACTURER_NAME, NULL, &nItemLen); 
    pItemBuff = (AECHAR*)MALLOC(nItemLen); 
    if (!pItemBuff) return; 
    ISHELL_GetDeviceInfoEx(s, AEE_DEVICEITEM_MANUFACTURER_NAME, pItemBuff, &nItemLen); 
    DBGPRINTF("id_%d: '%S'", id, pItemBuff); 

    FREE(pItemBuff); 
}
```