# Why does not detecting phone make and model work on HTC Smart?

Tags: brew-framework, brewmp

I can not seem to [detect handset make and model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760544/how-to-detect-phone-handset-brand-and-model-info-on-brew) on the Brew MP phone HTC Smart?  (Same as Dopod F3188 and HTC F3188.)

I am using `ISHELL_GetDeviceInfoEx(s, AEE_DEVICEITEM_MANUFACTURER_NAME, NULL, &nItemLen);`

Only empty strings are returned.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with the HTC Smart. I used conditional compiling for that handset instead.