# Alternative way to detect/fingerprint phone make and model?

Tags: api, version, detection, brew-framework, brewmp

As seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760687/why-does-not-detecting-phone-make-and-model-work-on-htc-smart), there is a problem with using OS supplied APIs to detect make and model of a particular handset. (In that case, an HTC Smart.)

Is there some other way to indirectly determine the make and model?  For instance, can one look for class ids only present on that particular phone, in combination with OS version perhaps, to detect make and model? I am hoping to avoid conditional compiling as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that only the HTC Smart is affected, all other phones seem to report version etc correctly.